# ckeditor disable element, prevent user from adding content to it

Tags: ckeditor, element

I've added a plugin that allows the user to add a specially styled div via a dialog. The issue now is, this element should not be clickable inside the edtior. The problem is the users manage it to click inside the div and enter text there and by this screw it up.

I've already spent some time searching the documentation but couldn't find the right approach to do this yet. I'm *not* asking for code, just some advice how to do it, a pointer to the right API method would be good enough for me. I guess I can somehow access the elements or intercept an users click and prevent them from adding something to my element somehow, I just couldn't yet figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to get this done by making the elements content not editable. When I create the element in my dialog:

```
hrElement.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```

When loading the plugin:

```
init: function (editor) {
    editor.on('contentDom', function () {
        var stiching = (this.document.getElementsByTag('div'));
        console.log(stiching);
        for(var i=0;i<stiching.count();i++){
            if (stiching.getItem(i).hasClass('stitching')) {
                stiching.getItem(i).setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is not the most best solution (don't like to iterate over the elements) but at least it works for me now. Any suggestions how to improve it for future cases are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Widget System](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widgets).

- [Widget Tutorial](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1).
- [Demos](http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets).

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really need a complete widget. All that was needed here is to insert an element that has a dashed border at bottom.

Comment: Widgets are wrappers for non-editable content and fix dozens of problems with them. But if your case is so simple, then you can start with pure `contenteditable=false` and see. Switching to widget will be very simple (actually, it will be even less code that you have currently).